# How can I use validation in Register form of Symfony with doctrine to maintain uniquness of username?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I want to validate username in database to check weather or not username is already register or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sfValidatorDoctrineUnique() for that.
Example of usage:

```
new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'sfGuardUser',
     'column' => array('username')),
     array('invalid'=>$this->__('Email is registrated')))
```

Comment: Thnx @Vadym, This was really helpful for me...Sorry I forget to inform you and also thankful.